# Multiply all Floats in a String

Tags: javascript

Let's say I've got a multiplier and a String

```
const mult = 2.5
const str = "2 apples, 7.3 grams sugar and around 13.52 grapes"
```

I want the output to be

```
const out = "5 apples, 18.25 grams sugar and around 33.8 grapes"
```

I tried using regex to go through the whole String, find floats, convert them, multiply and push it back into the String but I can't get it to work. Can someone help please?

Comment: "_I tried ... but I can't get it to work_" Can you show the attempt you made and explain what exactly is not working with it? Right now this is just asking us to do the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback.

```js
const mult = 2.5
const str = "2 apples, 7.3 grams sugar and around 13.52 grapes";
const res = str.replace(/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g, x => x * mult);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it wayyy overcomplicated but this is great!

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split(/([0-9.]+)/).map(x=>x*mult||x).join('')
```

The key is the parentheses around the regexp.  They make it capturing, so the number appears in the list